# Python telethon database is locked

Tags: python, database, telethon

I am using multiple scripts to automate some stuff. I am using here multiple accounts.
The accounts are rotating but sometimes 2 of my scripts try to use the same account at the same time then I get an sq3lite Error Database is locked. And the script stops. I know that this error occurs if the same session is trying to be used by 2 scripts.

How can I recode it so it doesnt stop there, but skips this account if that error happens and skips to the next account?

```
for x in range(0,9999):
    for account in accounts:
        client = TelegramClient(account, api_id, api_hash)
        try:
            await client.connect()
            if await client.is_user_authorized():
                #code here
        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            print('Error')
            continue
```